# Wamp apache rotatelog weird issue

Tags: apache, wamp, logrotate

I am trying to use wamp apache's rotatelog function to organize daily logs. However, I noticed that the access log is written to two places. The first file is the original access_log.log and the second file is written to the defined rotated log file.

The code added to httpd.conf to enable rotatelog is as follow.

```
CustomLog "|C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/bin/rotatelogs.exe C:/wamp64/backup/logs/apache/access_log/access_log_%d-%m-%y.log 86400" common
ErrorLog "|C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/bin/rotatelogs.exe C:/wamp64/backup/logs/apache/error_log/error_log_%d-%m-%y.log 86400"
```

Initially, I thought that enabling rotatelog will only write access log and error log to one file on a daily basics but it doesn't looks like it. Anyone know which part went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that I need to comment out the original CustomLog and ErrorLog configuration in httpd.conf and then add in the codes that I shown in the question. That would configure apache to only write to 1 access log file and error log file.